# Lazy Load Images Only After Bootstrap Modal has Opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, bootstrap-modal

I found two similar answers here but both were unsuccessful for my situation (given my limited ability to translate them to my situation). I have a page with a lot of fairly large images and the default method of Bootstrap is to load all the modal images upon page load. The visible html renders fairly quickly (I have a spinner for that) but the additional load time for the hidden modals makes the page impractical. I want the page to load only the visible (non-modal) content to complete the page load (and clear the spinner) and then load each modal's content only when that modal is fired. I've tried every lazyload solution I could find but the images will not render in the modal (the 'data-src' placeholders render but not the 'src' images that are supposed to replace them). I only want to lazyload (or load on 'show.bs.modal') the large images of the modal, those within the 'modal-body' class. I hope this is clear enough.

Sample code:

```
/* Javascript placed in the head */

<script>

function lazyLoad(){
    var $images = $('.lazy_load');

    $images.each(function(){
        var $img = $(this),
            src = $img.attr('data-src');

        $img
            .on('load',imgLoaded($img[0]))
            .attr('src',src);
        });
    };

    $('.modal-body').on("show.bs.modal", function () {
    lazyLoad();
};          

</script>

/* HTML in the modal section */


<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="galleryheader">
                <img src="headerimage_1.png" height="77" width="1024">
            </div>
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <div class="modal-body lazy_load">
                            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="images/largeimage_1A.jpg" height="585" width="800"class="img-centered" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body lazy_load">
                            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="images/largeimage_1A.jpg" height="585" width="800"class="img-centered" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body lazy_load">
                            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="images/largeimage_1A.jpg" height="585" width="800"class="img-centered" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="close-lower" data-dismiss="modal">
                <IMG SRC="images/close.jpg" WIDTH="85" HEIGHT="32"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, put the `lazy_load` class on the `img` element, not on the parent `div`. Secondly the jQuery you need is something like this:

```
$('.portfolio-modal').on("show.bs.modal", function () {
    $('.lazy_load').each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        img.attr('src', img.data('src'));
    });
});
```

Notes:

1. Use the `portfolio-modal` class to identify the modal.
2. Use the jQuery [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get the image to lazily load.

Comment: I have replaced the js exactly as you posted it and moved the '.lazy_load' class to the end of the <img> string ( <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="images/largeimage_1A.jpg" height="585" width="800"class="lazy_load" alt=""/> ). The page loads very fast, the placeholder images load, but the 'src' images still do not replace them. I'm wondering if there is something in the bootstrap.js that conflicts with this somehow, or if the 'show.bs.modal' function is not the way to go here (although logically it should be...)

Comment: @evanonearth It works fine for me, here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/7kS6Ube98u

Comment: Great! This works now. Thank you! 
I had the script tag for jquery above javascript in the header, I think that was the problem. Javascript needs to come first.